# Looking for an event/data/cron-triggered tasks workflow automation framework

Tags: automation, framework, workflow

I'm looking for a framework or project that can automate configurable task flows when a particular trigger is activated, or some data becomes available.

Here's a list of requirements:

- tasks can be chained
- tasks can be standalone executables
- support for task dependencies (eg. task C depends on data from A and B, so it will have to wait for both before starting)
- data can be passed between tasks
- task chains can be triggered either by an external event (eg. data becomes available) or through cron scheduling
- UI for workflow management
- deployable (not a web service)

Python/.NET would be preferred, but anything works really.

Something in the spirit of [If This Then That](https://ifttt.com/)/[Zapier](https://zapier.com/) combined with [Azkaban2](http://azkaban.github.io/)/[Luigi](https://github.com/spotify/luigi).

For the first part a quick search returns [Huginn](https://github.com/cantino/huginn), which looks promising, but wondering if there are other alternatives too.

Comment: Thanks, much better now (so let's cleanup above comments). Just the desired platform is missing; Android (concluded from IFTTT)? Whatever it is, could you please include it as well?

Comment: Did you ever find anything? I need the same thing exactly. It's like a mechanism does not exist in the open source for some reason. It's either highly abstracted ETL, DevOP's specific orchestration, or overly simplified IOT/Social/Bot scheduler widget things. Just need flexible `Job = API -> Workflow/Chain/Dependency -> API Out` with an "extension" system for good ol remote to remote translations.

Comment: I've used [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) at the time.